# I cannot find a way to use 'require' in html

Tags: javascript, import, requirejs, require, commonjs

I am now developing JS in html, but I'd got following error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

The code is just simple `subs = require("./subscriptions.json").subs;`.

To solve this problem, I first tried **`module` with `import`** and got another errors.
`<script type="module" src="subscribe.js"></script>`

1. `import { subs as subs } from "./subscriptions.json";` → `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`
2. `import subs from "./subscriptions.json";` → `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
3. `import * from "./subscriptions.json";` → `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'`
4. `import "./subscriptions.json";` → `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

This was same with `"fs"`, a JS module, so I gave it up and tried to use **`require.js`**(2.3.6). But similarly, it threw errors.
`<script data-main="subscribe.js" src="require.js"></script>`

1. `require(["./subscriptions.json"]);` → `Uncaught Error: Script error for "subscriptions.json"`
2. `require(["json!./subscriptions.json"]);` → `Uncaught Error: Script error for "json", needed by: json!subscriptions.json_unnormalized2` , `Uncaught Error: Script error for "subscriptions.json"` , `Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: json!subscriptions.json_unnormalized2`
3. `require(["fs"]);` → `Uncaught Error: Script error for "fs"`

What could be the problem in my code? When needed, I can share my full code.

ps. Actually I don't need to require or import something. I just want my independent JS files to share a `json` data. If there is a better way, share yours please. Thank you.

Comment: There is no `require` in HTML. `require` is [CJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). `fs` is a Node.js module, also not available in the browser.

Comment: @jabaa Then what's wrong with `import` and `require.js`?

Comment: Do you get error messages? I tried your `import` code and got `Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/subscriptions.json” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/json”).` It seems like you can only import JavaScript modules. You can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import. Have you installed `require.js`? How do you import it? Have you configured it? You can read https://requirejs.org/

Comment: @jabaa Understanded. I would save JSON in another way. And, I had installed `require.js` as a file and put `<script data-main="subscribe.js" src="require.js"></script>`. I guess there's no problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use require in es6 modules. require is used in node.js and to read a json file in your browser side javascript you can use the fetch api in your javascript file and can get data from .json file and use it in HTML

```
fetch("test.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but how can I use `fs` to save it again?

Comment: @dbld `fs` is a Node.js module, not available in the browser.

Comment: You can save the updated JSON in your browser storage. but can't write it to a file on your PC or server, for that you need to write a node.js api

Comment: @jabaa Oh, it's a bad news. Then how can I save a file with JS?

Comment: @hamza_hassan_44 I don't know well about browser storage. Can I send push to the browsers saved in it?

Comment: var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

Comment: @dbld it depends on your use-case what actually you want to achieve. If you can share maybe I could be able to suggest a solution

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: _"What could be the problem in my code?"_ The question mentions `import`, `fs` and `requirejs`. That can't be answered with a small code snippet. How would you import a module in a browser? Why does it not work with `requirejs`? Why does `import` not work?

Comment: @jabaa thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer

Comment: @hamza_hassan_44 I'm happy with solving a problem. But I want to solve another: saving. I am trying to develop Push API, which saves browser datas and sends a push to each browser. For that, I had to save browser datas in my local storage.

Comment: you can then save data to your browser storage as mentioned in the above comment.